# dry humor or “deadpan”

Tags: перевод

Как перевести на Русский "dry humor", "dry sense of humor" или "deadpan"?

"тонкий юмор"?

Comment: Сдержанный юмор, бесстрастный юмор

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Существует точный перевод. 
**Английский юмор.**

Answer (score 2):

Ещё можно перевести через определение: **хорошо скрываемый сарказм**.

Или вот выдержка из [статьи](http://daily.afisha.ru/archive/vozduh/archive/guide-to-summer-times/), где при переводе даётся транслитерация:

> Фильм снят в жанре **дедпэн**, что дословно на русский язык переводится
>   как «**комедия, в которой шутят с невозмутимым лицом**» — как, например,
>   это происходит у Вуди Аллена.

Пример такого юмора, который понимаешь не сразу:

> Mahatma Ghandi was asked by an English journalist what he thought of
>   Western Civilization. Ghandi replied, "Ahhh, that would be a very good
>   idea."

Answer (score 0):

Дело в том что значение слова humor происходит от "влага". Так что "сухой юмор" это выражение само по себе довольно забавное, как "сухая вода".
В другом форуме я уже пытался ответить что не всегда можно перевести humor однозначно как юмор. В зависимости от контекста это - общая манера поведения,  personality, или даже тип темперамента (была какая то древняя теория, будто 4 темперамента определяются преобладающей жидкостью организма - кровь, желчь и т.д.) Sense of humor - это чувство юмора, да.